# How to repeat an example with Ratchet Push?

Tags: php, websocket, xampp, zeromq, ratchet

I would like to repeat the Ratchet Push [example](http://socketo.me/docs/push). Downloaded Composer. In the project folder via the console (CLI) I entered: `php composer.phar require cboden/ratchet`, after which the vendor folder and a pair of files from Composer appeared. I installed ZeroMQ and tried two installation options:

1. Downloaded the necessary files from
   https://pecl.php.net/package/zmq/1.1.3/windows.
    - `libzmq.dll` unpacked in `C:\xampp\php`,
   - `php_zmq.php` in `C:\xampp\php\ext`.
   Added the `C:\xampp\php\ext` to system variable **`PATH`**,
   + restarted the computer,
    + restarted the web server.
2. Downloaded the necessary files from
   https://pecl.php.net/package/zmq/1.1.3/windows.
   - `libzmq.dll` unpacked
   in `C:\xampp\php\windowsXamppPhp`,
   - `php_zmq.php` in `C:\xampp\php\windowsXamppPhp\ext`.
   Added the `C:\xampp\php\windowsXamppPhp\ext` to system variable **`PATH`**,
   + restarted the computer,
   + restarted the web server.

I also tried to throw the file `libzmq.dll` into the same folder as `php_zmq.php`.

The installation was guided by:
https://wiki.zeromq.org/bindings:php
+ 
https://superuser.com/questions/585291/installing-...

After all, started the xampp server, then in the console entered: `php push-server.php`, but the console throws an error :

```
> PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'React\ZMQ\Context' not found
> in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\push-server.php:9 Stack trace:
> #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\push-server.php on line 9
> 
> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'React\ZMQ\Context' not found in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\test\push-server.php:9 Stack trace:
> #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\push-server.php on line 9
```

P.S.: I believe that something is wrong with the installation of ZeroMQ since the file was not working.

- ОС: windows 10
- Server: XAMPP
- PHP version: 7.4.2

Comment: Would you mind to post the output from call **`$ php -i | grep zmq`** ?